# Как сделать динамический массив слов в Си?

Tags: c, строки, инспекция-кода, динамические-массивы, malloc

Мне поставили задачу сделать ввод текста по словам, которые будут храниться в `words`. Я понял, что `char* words[]` - это массив слов. Мне нужно, чтобы выделялось определенное количество байт для каждого слова (кажется, у меня это получилось сделать, но не так, как надо)

Еще не получается остановить цикл ввода: не знаю как сделать условие остановки. Пробовал `tmp != EOF` и `if(scanf("%s", tmp) !=1);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE 100
#define MAX_STR_LEN 50

int main(){
    char* words[WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        words[i] = NULL;
    }


    char tmp[MAX_STR_LEN];//временный массив для слова
    for(int i = 0; i < WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE ; i++){
        scanf("%s", tmp);
//узнаю размер слова в массиве tmp и увеличиваю words[i]
        words[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(tmp)));
        if(words[i] == NULL){
        printf("faill");
        exit(0);
        }
//здесь я попытался поместить tmp в words но это не работает
        words[i] = tmp;
    }

    free(words);//ругается на это
    return 0;
}
```

И еще выдает ошибку `SIGABRT` в строке `free(words);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. указатель на выделенную память вы меняете на адрес локального массива

   ```
   words[i] = tmp;
   ```

,а нужно копирование строки с одного места памяти в другое с помощью

```
strcpy(words[i],tmp);
```

2. удалять локальный массив вы не имеете права, вы память для него не выделяли

   ```
   free(words);
   ```

всю память, что вы выделяли, от той и отказывайтесь

```
for(int i = 0; i < words_N ; i++)
  free (words[i]);
```

3. память выделяли мало, не хватает для конечного символа конца строки `'\00'`

   ```
   words[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(tmp) + 1));
   ```
4. чтобы закончить ввод строк, придумайте ключевое слово, и останавливайтесь, как удобно.

   ```
   if (strlen(tmp) == 1 && tmp[0] == 'X')  {
      words_N = i ;
      break;  }
   ```

---

```
// gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Winline -Os words.c -o words
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE 100
#define MAX_STR_LEN 50

int main(){
    char* words[WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        words[i] = NULL;
    }


    char tmp[MAX_STR_LEN];//временный массив для слова
    int words_N = WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE ;
    for(int i = 0; i < WORDS_ARRAY_SIZE ; i++){
        scanf("%s", tmp);
        
        // ключевое слово сделайте "X" для выхода
        if (strlen(tmp) == 1 && tmp[0] == 'X')  {
          words_N = i ;
          break;  }
          
//узнаю размер слова в массиве tmp и увеличиваю words[i]
        // память выделяли мало, не хватает для конечного символа конца строки '\00'
        words[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(tmp) + 1));
        if(words[i] == NULL){
        printf("faill");
        exit(0);
        }

        // указатель на выделенную память вы меняете на адрес локального массива
        // words[i] = tmp;
        // копируем строку из tmp в words[i]
        strcpy(words[i],tmp);
    }

    // free(words);
    // удалять локальный массив вы не имеете права, вы память для него не выделяли
    // всю память, что вы выделяли, от той и отказывайтесь
    for(int i = 0; i < words_N ; i++)
      free (words[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```